# save ajax response to a element that was not on the DOM

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have some results on the page (firts 10), then with a "load more result" button, I send the "id" of the last report to a PHP page.

I'v read here that I have to use .on (because .live is depreciated) so click event on new elements added to the DOM (through AJAX) can work.

My question is ... can I display somehow the content that came through AJAX on a div that was not on the initial DOM ?

```
$("#jokesWrap").on('click', 'a.share', function(event) {        

var joke_id = $(this).attr('name');

var msgbox = $("#success[name='" + joke_id + "']");

$("#post-to-wall[name='" + joke_id + "']").hide();

msgbox.html('<img src="includes/images/load.gif">&nbsp; Loading...');

$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST", 
        url: "includes/php/ajax.php", 
        data: "joke_id=" + joke_id, 
        success: function(msg)
            {
                if(msg == 'OK')
                    {
                        msgbox.html('<img src="includes/images/success.png" /> DONE!');
                    }
            } // function(msg)
    }); // ajax

event.preventDefault(); });
```

This is the HTML part:

```
<div id="jokesWrap">

<div class="joke" id="1">
    <p class="txt">
        some text
    </p>
    <div class="joke-options-bar">
        <a href="#" id="post-to-wall" class="share tip-this floatL" name="1" title="Post to wall">Post to wall</a>
        <span id="success" name="1" class="share floatL"></span>
        <br class="floatClear" />
    </div>
</div>
// the above area comes through loop from the ajax call
```

PS: Everything is ok: the ajax call (The tetxt is posted to the wall) the #post-to-wall is hidden. The "loding..." and the success message it's not shown.

PS2: the "Loading..." text and success message it's shown when I click on link that was on the DOM before the AJAX call ( because the #success was there)

Any help it's apprecied!

Comment: Looking at what seem to be edits to the question: Element IDs (specified with the `id` attribute) have to be unique throughout the entire document; that includes elements added later as part of an AJAX callback. You can't have multiple elements with an `id` of `success` - make them unique by doing away with the `name` attribute, and adding the value to the end of the `id` instead, so you'd have `success1, success2, etc` as your IDs.

Comment: and then append data to #success(uniqueID) ?

Comment: Yes, assuming that's the correct ID for the element you want to append to.

Comment: So change this: `var msgbox = $("#success[name='" + joke_id + "']");` to: `var msgbox = $("#success" + joke_id + "");` ?

Comment: Appending the empty string at the end is unnecessary (`"#success" + joke_id` works fine), but that's the general idea.

Comment: How can I select your suggestion as the answer of the question ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include my first comment (about IDs needing to be unique). There should be a tick next to it that you can click on to select that as the accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the element exists in the DOM when the `success` callback of the AJAX is executed, you can use jQuery to select and manipulate it in the same way as you would an element that **did** exist in the DOM when the page was initially loaded. Or you can use jQuery to create the element as part of the `success` callback, manipulate it using the response from the AJAX request, then append your newly created element to the DOM in the required position. Something like so:

```
var div = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'new-div-id').html(data);
$('body').append(div);
```

That creates a new `div`, gives it an `id` of `new-div-id`, then sets its innerHTML to be whatever `data` was (assuming `data` is the name of the variable that contains the response text from the AJAX), then finally appends it as a new child of the `<body>` tag of the page.

---

Looking at what seem to be edits to the question: Element IDs (specified with the `id` attribute) have to be unique throughout the entire document; that includes elements added later as part of an AJAX callback. You can't have multiple elements with an `id` of `success` - make them unique by doing away with the `name` attribute, and adding the value to the end of the `id` instead, so you'd have `success1, success2, etc` as your IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the DOM before writing to it?